# EMF sorting options with resource save api

Tags: emf

Our resource entities are getting sorted using Ascii values which produces an ordering that is inconsistent with human logic while doing an resource save.
using resource.save().

For eg: text1, text2, text 10 gets sorted as text1, text10 , text 2

We expect it to be sorted as text1, text2, text10.

Is there any way to get the entries sorted while we do a resource save,

or is there any other way to approach it ?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem. Afaik, EMF does not sort elements, and preserve the order in which elements were added.
If you add/insert elements in an order that is ok to you, it will be preserved in the corresponding resource.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [AlphanumericComparator](https://github.com/sawano/alphanumeric-comparator/blob/master/src/main/java/se/sawano/java/text/AlphanumericComparator.java) to handle this sorting.

If you wish to do that while saving an EMF resource, you'll need to create a custom [XMIResourceImpl](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.5.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/impl/XMLResourceImpl.html) and to override method `save()`.